# JSON multi dimension data in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, multidimensional-array

i have following structure:

```
var data = {
    "Form" : ["img1","img2"],
    "Provider" : ["img1","img2"]
};
```

i want to add sub object under Provider like this:

```
var data = {
    "Form" : ["img1","img2"],
    "Provider" : ["Memorial1" : "img1","img2"],
                 ["Memorial2" : "img1","img2"]

};
```

I tried it with following code:

```
obj['Provider'].push({
        "Memorial1" : ["img1"]          
});
```

I get :

```
{
   "Form" : ["img1","img2"],
   "Provider" : [{"Memorial1" : ["img1"]},
                {"Memorial1" : ["img1"]}]

};
```

I am not able to retrieve Memorial1 values from above i tried with this:

```
data['Provider']['Memorial1']
```

it returns undefined

Can anybody tell me what i am doing wrong?

Update:

I found the solution:

```
var data ='{"Form":[],"Provider":[{"Memorial" : ["img2"]},{"Memorial2":["img3"]}]}'; //correct format
var data = JSON.parse(data); // parse the json

alert(data['Provider'][0]['Memorial1']); // returns img2

alert(data['Provider'][0]['Memorial2']); // returns img3
```

Comment: `data['Provider']` is an Array, as of that it has to be: `data['Provider'][0]['Memorial1']`, `data['Provider'][1]['Memorial1']`, ...

Comment: Your "like this" is invalid. If you give us a valid example of what you want, we can help you; if you don't, we'd be guessing.

Comment: I tried with data['Provider'][0]['Memorial1'] but no luck @t.niese

Comment: I think you did not get what i asked : 
**i want to add sub object under Provider like this**

That means i want to get the structure i posted. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: You said `I am not able to retrieve Memorial1 values from above i tried with this:` and `Can anybody tell me what i am doing wrong?`  So  you  ask how to retrieve the data from the structure you got (the below `I get :`) and my comment shows you how to do that, as you can see in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/umeLxh2o/1/) the `data['Provider'][0]['Memorial1']` will output `["img1"]`. `No luck` is not very descriptive. What did you expect that should be returned?

Comment: That is the case it should return ["img1"] but is returning error.

Error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined @t.niese

Comment: If you get `Cannot read property '0' of undefined` then an early call `data['Provider'].push(` would also have failed. So you probably screw yourself with a messy code, and wrong variable names, in your question you at least have `data` and `obj`. As you can see the example works. So the problem is in your actual code. But you only show some snippet to it, so is impossible to guess what you do wrong.

Comment: *"That means i want to get the structure i posted"* **Again**: That structure is **not valid**. Try it in your browser. So **again**, if you show us a *valid* example of what you're trying to achieve, we can help you.

Comment: In my case i use obj, Regarding obj['Provider'].push( this works as i can get it working in console.log. Issue is when i retrieve these values.@t.niese

Comment: This structure is wrong ? var data = {
    "Form" : ["img1","img2"],
    "Provider" : ["Memorial1" : "img1","img2"],
                 ["Memorial2" : "img1","img2"]

};

or this one : 

{
   "Form" : ["img1","img2"],
   "Provider" : [{"Memorial1" : ["img1"]},
                {"Memorial1" : ["img1"]}]

}; @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @websterz: Yes. Again, try it. `["Memorial1" : "img1", "img2"]` is a syntax error. *Maybe* you mean `{"Memorial1": ["img1", "img2"]}`, but maybe not, and in any case we shouldn't have to guess.

Comment: Well i need the correct format as of sub objects.. what should be the correct format ? i believe you got my problem. 

I need to push and retrieve data as i retrieve it from single object : obj['Provider'] so for sub object under provider named "Memorial" i need to get data obj['Provider']['Memorial'] so it should return ["img1"] @T.J.Crowder how do i achieve this

Comment: If you need help with basic syntax, such as array initializers and object initializers, I suggest working through JavaScript tutorials. (And no, I don't know what you're trying to achieve, which is why I've repeatedly said that.)

Comment: Thank you T.J Crowder Well i could not find any proper format for sub objects. Can you give me an example of. @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score -1):

The `data['Provider']` is an array. So, to get `Memorial1` of the first entry, you can do:

```
data['Provider'][0]['Memorial1']
```

Where the `[0]` indicates array access to the first entry. Then, `[1]` would be the second, and so on.

Comment: Tried with this, but no luck. As i am pushing the data by :

obj['Provider'].push({
        "Memorial1" : ["img1"]          
});

That can be the reason ? seems not recognizing as array or object ?

Comment: What is `obj`? If you mean `data`, try to `console.log(data['Provider'])` to see what it is. It should be an array, and then you can `.push` to it without any issue. If it is not, well, it should be obvious (might be a string?)

Comment: Yes it is array:

Provider:Array[1]
0:Object 
length:1
__proto__: Array[0]

Answer (score -1):

Found the Solution:

```
var data ='{"Form":[],"Provider":[{"Memorial" : ["img2"]},{"Memorial2":["img3"]}]}'; //correct format
var data = JSON.parse(data); // parse the json

alert(data['Provider'][0]['Memorial1']); // returns img2

alert(data['Provider'][1]['Memorial2']); // returns img3
```